# Do expressions mean anything?

Tags: recettear-an-item-shops-tale

Okay, so in Recettear, when you sell stuff to people their expressions change from time to time. However, I have not found any logic on how these works. Sometimes they smile and refuse to pay, sometimes they look worried and accept straight away.

Do these faces customers make impact the gameplay anyway or are they just graphics without meaning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The smiles/etc are just background color; they're not intended to convey information if memory serves.  So this character might appear stern while that one appears jovial, but it's just to give things visual variety  What you really care about is:

1. Did I get a near pin or pin (this increases the XP you gain; it's important to level your merchant level as rapidly as possible).  There is no visual queue for near pin/pin that I can find right now.
2. Did the customer get a little heart near their head after the transaction?  If so, that means you leveled your reputation level with that customer.  This is **critical**; it increases their budget and allows you to sell them more expensive items.

Comment: Guessed so. Wanted to be sure. Thanks for confirming it. AFAIK there is no way to guess what pin prices are, except trying to guess how much money each one carries. I prefer crating "Just" combos, since they are easiest to form.

Comment: Pin prices are hard to nail down, but generally the type of customer lends itself towards guesstimating. Men tend to be willing to pay more (I generally charge anywhere from 120-130% based on the person) while women seem to be more... fastidious with their money (little girls tend to favor 105% of the base price).